# How do you script movement of two or more characters at the same time?

Tags: scene, rpg-maker-mv

Its not quite clear how to move 2 characters at the same time from and to fixed positions.  Within the tutorials for RPG Maker MV users are shown how to script the movement of single characters at a time to fixed positions.  In the tutorials, users are also shown how to have multiple characters moving at the same time in random directions or possibly in repeating loops.  However, its not quite clear how to move 2 or more characters at the same time in a one-time scripted manner.

For example, at the start of a conversation, its normal to move the characters to specific screen positions so that they can begin uttering dialogue much like actors on a stage.  However, the only way I know how to do this is moving one character at a time, which you often see in many classic jrpgs.   In the modern age, however we have a lot more tools and resources at our disposal, so it doesn't seem necessary to move them one at a time. Why not just have them move at the same time so the player doesn't have to watch a second or two of rapid sequential movement?

Is there a way to script the movement of 2 characters at the same time to fixed positions so that they can begin speaking cutscene dialog?

**How does one script simultaneous movement of characters that is not random or looped?**

<sub>I don't have enough rep yet to create an rpg maker mv tag.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its fairly easy to create simultaneous movement in RPG Maker MV, the key is to uncheck the 'Wait for Completion' checkbox on all but the last movement route in the set of movement routes within the triggering event.  If you don't select the 'Wait for Completion' then the rest of your event may go haywire as the rest of the event script will fire once movement is started.

The steps are fairly easy.

1. Create each character event if they aren't already created  If you don't already have ones
2. Create a separate event that will trigger the simultaneous movement. If it wasn't already created.
3. In the separate actual event create the movement routes but uncheck the 'Wait For Completion' checkbox in the '**Options**' panel of the '*Set Movement Route*' dialog box, except for the last route.  The last route **should** have the 'Wait For completion' checkbox selected.
4. Click 'OK' to close the event editor.

[image: Wait for completion selection]

Test and the movement should work as expected at this point.  Sometimes you have to do this more than once in an event if you have multiple sets movement routes that you want to happen at the same time.  For each set you need to have one 'Wait for Completion' route at the end of the subset of routes.